# IE Caching Issue with Image Rotator

Tags: caching

We have an issue for IE browsers (only) whereby our image rotator only rotates once before failing. To see the problem in action, please view the following URL. NOTE: The issue is only apparent with your IE "Check for Newer Versions of stored pages" set to "Automatic"

http://www.allblacks.com/

How can we resolve this issue for users who happen to have "Automatic" as their setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/40a6fcec-089e-4a70-bfc5-b2939ccc7ba3

Though I'd have thought setting the correct meta information in the HTML page header would've been sufficient, but apparently not.

Go the All Blacks!! Bring back Christian Cullen!! Down with Dan Carter!!